Ergodic hierarchy and the two-point correlation function
I'm currently looking at a paper about dual unitary circuits (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.02140) where the authors derive an expression for the correlation function looking like
$$C_{\alpha\beta} = \sum_k c_{k}^{\alpha\beta}\lambda_k^t$$
where $t$ is time, $\lambda_k$ are the eigenvalues of some unistochastic map meaning that they are bounded to the unit disc, i.e. $\mid\lambda_k\mid \leq 1$ and $c_{k}^{\alpha\beta}$ is some scalar value.
Now, on page $4$ of this paper they create an ergodic hierarchy of the system depending on the eigenvalues $\lambda_k$. To restate:

Non-ergodic (Interacting and nonintegrable): There are $K$ eigenvalues equal to $1$ where $K$ is between $1$ and the maximum amount of eigenvalues. This implies that these $K$ modes remain constant.
Ergodic and non-mixing: All eigenvalues $\lambda_k \neq 1$. There is, however, at least one eigenvalue with unit modulus $\mid \lambda_k\mid=1$. This implies that the correlation function will never decay but oscillate.
Ergodic and mixing: All eigenvalues lie within the unit circle, $\mid \lambda_k\mid<1$. All the correlations will decay exponentially.

I have basically two questions now:

Where does all of this come from? Are there maybe any references which talk about all of this definitions? So, for example, why is case $3$ called ergodic and mixing while case $2$ is ergodic and non-mixing?
How can one prove that in case 3 you have exponential decay,  with a decay rate $\Delta = 1-\mid\lambda_{max}\mid$, of the correlation function for long times? Here, $\lambda_{max}$ is the largest eigenvalue. I thought about replacing $\lambda_k$ with $\mid\lambda_{max}\mid$ to get $$C_{\alpha\beta} \leq \sum_k c_{k}^{\alpha\beta}(1-\Delta)^t = De^{t\log(1-\Delta)}.$$ Since $1-\Delta < 1$ it is clear that this will decay to zero, but isn't the decay rate $\log(1-\Delta)$ here? I see that it will be $\Delta$ alone if $\Delta$ is very small and you can Taylor expand the logarithm but is that always justified?

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out a little bit with this one. Would also be really happy if anyone could link some good references where maybe all of this is discussed in more detail. Thank you!
